# CamelCase with accents and acronyms

Tags: regex, sed, terminal

Using sed I'm trying to split CamelCase occurrences in a text file.
I've came up with this code, however it fails in some cases.

```
$ sed 's/\([A-Z]\)/ \1/g' input.txt > output.txt
```

input:

```
IstoÉumTeste
BlaBlaBla
TestingAcronymsABCandAnotherOneKYI
```

output:

```
 Isto Éum Teste
 Bla Bla Bla
 Testing Acronyms A B Cand Another One K Y I
```

It fails when an "accent" or an acronym steps in the way...

expected output:

```
Isto É um Teste
Bla Bla Bla
Testing Acronyms ABC and Another One KYI
```

EDIT:
For my case I use Portuguese special characters: àáéãõçÀÁÉÃÕÇ

Comment: Looks like there is no free lunch of a ready-made regex for accented letters. Please provide a list of everything you want considered an accented upper case letter and everything you want considered an accented lower case letter.

Comment: Are you sure your expected output is `É um` and not `Éum`? If yes, why the inconsistency?

Comment: Yes I'm sure! There are two different words in Portuguese... The mechanism is the same as for other words.

Comment: If you expect from `sed` to properly tokenize Portuguese, the rules are going to be **a lot more complex** than you hope for.

Comment: As @randomir has hinted, your desired output, split between the uppercase letter "É" and "um" is not explained by the rule "split camelcase words". That special case desire is caused, as you explained, by the special single letter word È in portuguese. You probably need a list of those special cases to split explicitly.

Comment: @Yunnosch I've just add the accented letters you ask for. I hope you could help me... àáéãõçÀÁÉÃÕÇ

Comment: You also need to provide the list of special cases, words which should be split against/additionally the camelcase rule. Are there any other single letter words you want to split from the following lower case?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
$ sed -E -e 's/([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])/\1 \2/g' -e 's/([[:upper:]]{2,})([[:lower:]])/\1 \2/g' input.txt
Isto Éum Teste
Bla Bla Bla
Testing Acronyms ABC and Another One KYI
```

First, to handle Unicode characters, we should use `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]` character classes (instead of ASCII-only `[A-Z]`), because those include all uppercase and lowercase Unicode chars (at least on those `sed`s that support Unicode, like for example GNU `sed`).

Second, to handle acronyms (and prefix whitespace), we can split the problem in two subproblems: (1) splitting on `lower<to>UPPER` boundary, and (2) splitting on `ACRONYM<to>word` boundary.

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't solve the accent problem... ("Éum")

Comment: Does your `sed` support Unicode chars? I know GNU `sed` does, but I'm not sure for others.

Comment: Can you try running this `echo 'Éə' | sed 's/\([[:upper:]]\)/x/g'` in your shell and report the result?

Comment: This was the output: xə

Comment: Looks like your `sed` supports Unicode then. What encoding you use in `input.txt`?

Comment: I'm using UTF-8

Comment: Hmm.. It works perfectly fine for me on GNU sed, Linux. Which sed/OS you use?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint with GNU sed 4.2.2.
I think you're missing the accent char! Your output is not right, so it's impossible that it worked for you. Please confirm it.

Comment: The output is right, if you wish to split CamelCaseWords, with support for accents (Unicode) and acronyms. The output is wrong if it has to obey some implicit rules (like Portuguese support!).

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

### Brief

This was a head scratcher and I don't know if this will work in sed as it's PCRE regex. Regardless, this may help others with similar requests using other languages, so I'll post it as a potential answer.

---

### Code

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/g3WuWI/1)

```
((?(?=[A-Z])(?:[A-Z]\p{Ll}+|[A-Z]+)|\p{Lu})|\p{Ll}+)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
IstoÉumTeste
BlaBlaBla
TestingAcronymsABCandAnotherOneKYI
```

#### Output

```
Isto É um Teste 
Bla Bla Bla 
Testing Acronyms ABC and Another One KYI
```

---

### Explanation

- `((?(?=[A-Z])(?:[A-Z]\p{Ll}+|[A-Z]+)|\p{Lu})|\p{Ll}+)` Capture either of the following

  - `(?(?=[A-Z])(?:[A-Z]\p{Ll}+|[A-Z]+)|\p{Lu})` If clause specifying the following

    - `(?=[A-Z])` If what follows is an alpha uppercase letter
    - If **true**: `(?:[A-Z]\p{Ll}+|[A-Z]+)` Match either of the following

      - `[A-Z]\p{Ll}+` Match an uppercase alpha letter, followed by one or more lowercase letters (in any language)
      - `[A-Z]+` Match one or more uppercase alpha letters
    - If **false**: `\p{Lu}` Match an uppercase letter (in any language)
  - `\p{Ll}+` Match any lowercase letter (in any language)

---

---

## Edit

### Code

[See this code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/g3WuWI/2)

```
([A-Z]\p{Ll}+|[A-Z]+|\p{Lu}|\p{Ll}+)
```

Apparently overthinking it originally, this trimmed down version may be better supported.

Comment: `sed` does not support PCRE.

Comment: @zppinto I'm not sure if sed's extended regex mode will work with this, but you can try using the `-r` option

Comment: @randomir I didn't think it would, this answer may not work for sed (unless the option `-r` does), but it still may help others solve similar issues in other languages

Comment: No, the `-r` (or `-E`) option activates Extended Regex support (ERE), and not PCRE.

Comment: @randomir I've added an edit that no longer uses if/else. This may work better

Comment: @zppinto I don't think sed fully supports unicode unfortunately: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60481/match-word-containing-characters-beyond-a-za-z you may need to use an external tool like perl